# PHP 15 minute rounding

Tags: php, algorithm

In PHP I need to do a count of 15 minutes within a number of hours and minutes.  But I need it to round down if less or equal to 7 minutes and round up if over 7 minutes.

So I have something like;

```
$totalHours = 10;
$totalMinutes = 46;
```

The hours is easy enough to work out the number of 15 minutes;

```
$totalHours = 10*4;
```

But the minutes is giving me some grief.

Some examples are;

If Minutes = 7 then answer is 0.

If Minutes = 8 then answer is 1.

If Minutes = 18 then answer is 1.

If Minutes = 37 then answer is 2.

If Minutes = 38 then answer is 3.

I would be really grateful if someone could do me a nice function for this.  A signature of (int TotalHours, int TotalMinutes) would be great.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I think if Minutes = 38 then answer is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
echo round($n/15);
?>
```

// where n is your minute number i.e. 7, 8, 18, 37, 38 etc

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the number of minutes as (60 * hours + minutes), then add 8, divide by 15, and truncate the result by a call to int().

Answer (score 1):

To round to the nearest X: Divide by x, round to nearest int, multiply by x.

```
$nearest = round($minutes / 15) * 15;
```

But in your case, if you just want a count of that, you can simply skip the last step.

```
$numberOfQuarterHours = round($minutes / 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try modulo operation.

[PHP.net MOD](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php)

Just divide by 15 and get the remaining part. There you could apply test for 7 < x < 8